# The probability that the output of the experiment is Y is

Tags: probability

### Question

> Consider the following experiment.
>
> Step 1. Flip a fair coin twice.
>
> Step 2. If the outcomes are (TAILS, HEADS) then output Y and stop.
>
> Step 3. If the outcomes are either (HEADS, HEADS) or (HEADS, TAILS), then output N and stop.
>
> Step 4. If the outcomes are (TAILS, TAILS), then go to Step 1.
>
> The probability that the output of the experiment is Y is ?

### My Approach

Let the probability that the output of the experiment is $Y=p$

probability for the outcome to be  $(TAILS, HEADS)$ $$=\frac {1}{4} $$

probability for the outcome to be  $ either (HEADS, HEADS) or (HEADS, TAILS)$ $$=\frac {2}{4} $$

From the above information given, we can write the equation as-:

$$p=\frac {1}{4}+\frac {2}{4}+\frac {1}{4} \times p$$

$$p=\frac {1}{3}$$

Although there are many method to solve this , but i am only interseted in this method(above).Is it correct?

Comment: The idea looks good but there is a flaw.  The solution to $p=\frac 14+\frac 24+\frac 14\times p$ is $p=1$.  I think you meant to multiply the $\frac 24$ by $0$ (as there is no hope of success along that path).

Comment: @lulu :yes you are right ..! but i am afraid that if i mutiply $\frac{2}{4}$ with $0$ then,it will not harm the equation!

Comment: What's the problem?  the correct equation is $p=\frac 14\times 1 +\frac 24\times 0 +\frac 14\times p\implies p=\frac 14+\frac 14\times p\implies 4p=1+p\implies p=\frac 13$.

Comment: okk..thanks a lot